# rightmark without numbering?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'd like to include the section name in the header WITHOUT the section number.

The only instructions I could find on how to do this said to add this:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
```

...but when I added that, the section name never changed at all -- the header just displayed "Contents" for the whole document.

Thoughts?

I'm using Emacs org-mode to generate LaTeX. Here's what the template looks like.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hyperref,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true,linktocpage,pdftitle={\@title},pdfauthor={\@author},xetex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \setromanfont{Adobe Garamond Pro}
  \setsansfont{Arial}
  \setmonofont{Courier}
\else
  \usepackage[mathletters]{ucs}
  \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\fi
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\hypersetup{ colorlinks, citecolor=SteelBlue4,filecolor=SteelBlue4,linkcolor=SteelBlue4,urlcolor=SteelBlue4}
\makeatletter
\def\maketitle{
    {\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont \textbf{\@title}\par}
    {\Huge {\textit{\@author}\par}}
    {\Large \@date\par}
   \end{raggedright}
  \null
  \cleardoublepage
}

\usepackage{paralist}
\let\itemize\compactitem
    \let\description\compactdesc
    \let\enumerate\compactenum  
    \let\description\compactdesc
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
    \lhead{\href{mailto:cycleofsong@gmail.com}{Peter Salazar}}
    \chead{}
    \rhead{{\@title}: {\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
    \lfoot{}
    \cfoot{\thepage}
    \rfoot{}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \lstnewenvironment{code}{\lstset{language=Haskell,basicstyle=\small\ttfamily}}{}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{12pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
    \usepackage{fancyvrb}
    \usepackage{enumerate}
    \usepackage{ctable}
    \setlength{\paperwidth}{8.5in}
    \setlength{\paperheight}{11in}
     \usepackage[margin=1.5in,hmargin=1.5in,vmargin=1.5in]{geometry}
      \tolerance=1000
    \usepackage{tocloft}
    \renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
    \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
    \newcommand{\textsubscr}[1]{\ensuremath{_{\scriptsize\textrm{#1}}}}

          [NO-DEFAULT-PACKAGES]
          [NO-PACKAGES]"
         ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
         ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
         ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
         ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
         ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}")))
```

Comment: Make a small but complete example that demonstrates your problem so that we don't have to guess what packages and commands you are using. You can add pages with `\newpage abc \newpage ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Your file is neither minimal nor complete.  Cutting it down, this seems to work:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hyperref,x11names]{xcolor}

\title{Fake Title}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mytitle}{\@title}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\lhead{\href{mailto:cycleofsong@gmail.com}{Peter Salazar}}
\chead{}
\rhead{{\mytitle}: {\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{}

\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{colorlinks}

\begin{document}

\section{First}
a \newpage b \newpage c \newpage
\section{Second}
a \newpage b \newpage c \newpage
\section{Third}
a \newpage b \newpage c \newpage

\end{document}
```

One of the problems is that you are using a lot of `\@<something>` commands, which need to dealt with more carefully than normal macros (unless you externalize the set-up by putting it all in a `.sty` file of your own).

Anyway, here we have a section name in the header without a number.

Note, also, that `hyperref` should be one the last packages you load in any `.tex` file.